# adding Python to the path with bash

Tags: python, bash

I tried to install numpy with pip3 and I get this warning:

```
  *WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py3 and f2py3.8 are installed in '/home/smail/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.*
```

Then I tried to this:
`/Users/<you>/.bashrc`
and add this to the last of the line : `export PATH=/Users/<you>/Library/Python/3.8/bin:$PATH`

but I get this message : `*No such file or directory* please any thoughts about what I did wrong.`

Comment: That's not the directory mentioned in the warning.

Comment: maybe you need quote `PATH="/Users//Library/Python/3.8/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: What operating system are you on? The warning mentions a Linux-like path while you tried to add a macOS-like path.

Answer (score 0):

The path you need to add (which looks like a path in a Linux/other Unix system) is not the one you tried to add (which looks like a macOS path); you should rather do

```
PATH=/home/smail/.local/bin:$PATH
```

and restart your shell.